# Splitting a pandas dataframe values in a columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that a columns with some ID for companies. How can I split this ID in columns?

In this column the values can be 0(NaN) to more than 5 IDs, how to divide each one of them in separate columns?

Here is an example of the column:

```py
0                                                  4773300
1                                                      NaN
2                                  6201501,6319400,6202300
3                                                  8230001
4                                                      NaN
5           4742300,4744004,4744003,7319002,4729699,475470
```

The division would be at each comma, I imagine an output like this:

| columnA | columnB | columnC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4773300 | Nan | Nan |
| NaN | Nan | Nan |
| 6201501 | 6319400 | 6202300 |
| 8230001 | Nan | Nan |

And so on depending on the number of IDs

Comment: How are you going to handle it if there are more than 3 columns? Are you going to set the number of columns beforehand ?

Comment: The idea is to create a new column for each value

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `.str.split` method to perform this type of transformation quite readily. The trick is to pass the `expand=True` parameter so your results are put into a DataFrame instead of a Series containing list objects.

```py
>>> df
                                               ID
0                                         4773300
1                                             NaN
2                         6201501,6319400,6202300
3                                         8230001
4                                             NaN
5  4742300,4744004,4744003,7319002,4729699,475470


>>> df['ID'].str.split(',', expand=True)
         0        1        2        3        4       5
0  4773300     None     None     None     None    None
1      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN
2  6201501  6319400  6202300     None     None    None
3  8230001     None     None     None     None    None
4      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN
5  4742300  4744004  4744003  7319002  4729699  475470
```

---

You can also clean up the output a little for better aesthetics

- replace None for NaN
- alphabetic column names (though I would opt to not do this as you'll hit errors if a given entry in the ID column has > 26 ids in it.)
- join back to original DataFrame

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from string import ascii_uppercase
>>> (
    df['ID'].str.split(',', expand=True)
    .replace({None: float('nan')})
    .pipe(lambda d: 
        d.set_axis(
            pd.Series(list(ascii_uppercase))[d.columns], 
            axis=1
        )
    )
    .add_prefix("column")
    .join(df)
)

   columnA  columnB  columnC  columnD  columnE columnF                                              ID
0  4773300      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN                                         4773300
1      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN                                             NaN
2  6201501  6319400  6202300      NaN      NaN     NaN                         6201501,6319400,6202300
3  8230001      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN                                         8230001
4      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN                                             NaN
5  4742300  4744004  4744003  7319002  4729699  475470  4742300,4744004,4744003,7319002,4729699,475470
```

Comment: This apparently works! Could you use the append method to join these new columns to the rest of the dataset?

Comment: You can use `.join` to do that. I just updated my answer with some data cleaning tricks as well as the usage of `.join` to join these new columns back to the original DataFrame.

Comment: This error appears for the string library: "ImportError: cannot import name 'asccii_uppercase' from 'string'". How can we change to a number in column "Column1, Column2, ..."?

Comment: Apologies, that's a typo on my part. The correct import is `from string import ascii_uppercase`

Comment: Unfortunately this error returned, I confess that I did not understand.

KeyError: '[26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98] not in index'

Would it be related to the number of columns?

Comment: It's exactly related to the number of columns- this solution only uses the letters A-Z so it implicitly assumes none of your rows have more than 26 ids, which doesn't seem to be the case. If you want excel-like column lettering you'll need to write a function to do that. I'd recommend to just use numbered columns instead of translating them to letters.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too. Thanks for your help! Really! May I ask for one last tip? I saw that you created many columns (almost 100) what is the easiest way to keep only 5 of them?

Comment: Once you create that wide DataFrame, you can slice it using `.iloc[:, :5]` to keep the first 5 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Consider each entry as a string, and parse the string to get to individual values.

```
from ast import literal_eval
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', converters={'company': literal_eval})

words = []
for items in df['company']:
    for word in items:
        words.append(word)
```

FYI, This is a good starting point. I do not know what is intended output format needed as of now, since your question is kind of incomplete.